# move towards center from two ends in android

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es

[image]

How can i show progress of red and green colors towards each other from two extreme end points. I tried to do animation for it. How to use ValueAnimator to progress them each other.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide at least some code you used so far, to start with?
And could you clarify (e. g. a sketch) what kind of animation you want to achieve? The rectangles getting wider and finally connecting each other? I can´t imagine what you want.